# Will MS Project 2003 plugin support MS Project 2013?

Tags: ms-office, add-in, ms-project

Whether the Addin developed for MS Project 2003 will work in MS Project 2013?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it won't.

There is a slim chance that the core code may run ok, but with the switch from the menu bar to the ribbon menu, any menu options presented by the 2003 plug in won't be presented as buttons on the ribbon in 2013, so I can say with certainty that part won't work.

Comment: We have many add-ins that were written for Project 2003 that worked fine on Project 2010. What changed in Project 2013 that would make them not work?

Comment: How are the add-in commands executed? If they were triggered from a dropdown menu, then you can't run them in 2010 as there isn't a dropdown menu.

Comment: Our add-ins used a CommandBar, aka a toolbar. These show up in the add-ins tab of the ribbon.

Comment: Ah, I see, rather than drop down menus. I've found most of my 2010 code works in 2013, so hopefully they'll keep working for you if you upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

I can also confirm that COM Add Ins written for Project 2003 can work fine in Project 2007, 2010, 2013, and 2016. As noted above, the toolbar controls just move to the Add-Ins tab of the ribbon.   If you launched from menu items as well as toolbar controls, those launch points will be lost, but you don't really need those if you have something on the ribbon.

All of this is predicated on using a subset of the COM Interop interface that is 'core', e.g. supported on all versions of MS Project.  Microsoft tends to maintain these interfaces pretty well.  They may add new stuff in later versions, but I've found that they generally don't drop the old interfaces.   You will need to decide which version of the Primary Interop assemblies for building an application to be used across all these Project versions. I've seen advice that says you need to build a separate add-in binary for each version of MS Project, but I've never found a need to do that. You might be able to stick with the PIA from MS Project 2003, but I'd suggest you pick something like Project 2010 or Project 2013 Primary Interop Assemblies.

Hope this helps.